# Using Python and BeautifulSoup (saved webpage source codes into a local file)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Python 2.7 + BeautifulSoup 4.3.2.

I am trying to use Python and BeautifulSoup to pick up information on a webpage. Because the webpage is in the company website and requires login and redirection, I copied the target page's source code page into a file and saved it as “example.html” in C:\ for the convenience of practicing.

This is a part of the original code:

```
<tr class="ghj">
    <td><span class="city-sh"><sh src="./citys/1.jpg" alt="boy" title="boy" /></span><a href="./membercity.php?mode=view&amp;u=12563">port_new_cape</a></td>
    <td class="position"><a href="./search.php?id=12563&amp;sr=positions" title="Search positions">452</a></td>
    <td class="details"><div>South</div></td>
    <td>May 09, 1997</td>
    <td>Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

The code I worked out so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

url = "C:\example.html"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

cities = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'city-sh'})

for city in cities:
print city
```

This is just the first stage of testing, so it's somewhat incomplete.

However, when I run it, it gives an error message. Seems it’s improper to use `urllib2.urlopen` to open a local file.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\Testing.py", line 8, in <module>
     page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
     response = self._open(req, data)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 427, in _open
     'unknown_open', req)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
     result = func(*args)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1247, in unknown_open
     raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
 URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: c>
```

How can I practice using a local file?

Comment: please try: `soup = BeautifulSoup(open(url).read())` and note url should be `url = r"C:\example.html"` otherwise `\\` in url act as escape character.

Comment: thank you, Chandan. i change it to url = r"C:\example.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read()), and it works. the "urllib2.url" is useless here in my case.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With Chandan's help, the problem has been solved. All the credits shall go to him. :)

the "urllib2.url" is useless here.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
# import urllib2

url = "C:\example.html"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

cities = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'city-sh'})

for city in cities:
    print city
```

Comment: If `urllib2.url` is useless, then do you still need the `import urllib2`?

Comment: I would replace . 
`soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())`

with 
`soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), features="lxml")` in order to properly be able to navigate the DOM.

Comment: @Haddock-san, I have recent findings at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300101/illegal-multibyte-sequence-error-from-beautifulsoup-when-python-3, you may want to have a look.

Answer (score 137):

The best way to open a local file with BeautifulSoup is to pass it a file handler directly. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("C:\\example.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')

for city in soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'city-sh'}):
    print(city)
```

Comment: It shows the warning. The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511544/how-to-get-rid-of-beautifulsoup-user-warning)

Comment: On Macs, `soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/path/to/your/file.html"), "html.parser")`

Comment: The best way? It shows ResourceWarning: unclosed file

Comment: @MatejJ Thanks for heads up. Looks like they updated the docs / how it works. Now it doesn't handle closing for you. Updated to match new documentation using context manager.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using lxml parser also. Here is an example for your html data.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import lxml.html as PARSER

data = open('example.html').read()
root = PARSER.fromstring(data)

for ele in root.getiterator():
    if ele.tag == "td":
        print ele.text_content()
```

o/p:
port_new_cape
452
South
May 09, 1997
Jan 23, 2009 12:05 pm