# How to find non-i18n string in Symfony's Twig templates

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, translation

How to programmatically determine that a string in a template doesn't translated? I mean a case when a message doesn't enclosed by `{% trans %}` or `trans()`.

Like here:

```
<h1>Hello, world</h1> - miss trans tag
```

Actually, I have really much amount of templates in my applications and I need to know which message and in which template I could missed a trans tag.

Comment: So you are looking for text that's static? Only in HTML files?

Comment: I think, yes. Files are named something like: index.html.twig, landing.html.twig. And without Twig's interpretation they are simple html code. it's example one of such files: https://pastebin.com/S05SJvzG

Answer (score 0):

You could use a screen scraping/html parser library such as [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Here's an [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21570780/783284) on how to use it with a local HTML file.

However, unless you're going to be using this quite often (or it's a massive project) I'd imagine it would be less work to just look through the files manually.

I suggested BS since it's Python and it might be closer to PHP for you but there's also [JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) or [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex). I looked around, but don't see any HTML linters that also check for potential localization...

Edit: I also found this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/783284) with suggestions for PHP specifically.

Comment: So, I hoped to find solutions which was written on PHP. But your suggestions looks prospectively. I will try to use these parsers and then I will write about my experience. Thank you.

Comment: @MikhailSchedrakov I've added a link to an SO post with more options for PHP.