# Robobrowser and local files

Tags: python-3.x, robobrowser

I am a beginner using Python 3.6.4 and RoboBrowser 0.5.3.
I have saved some HTML webpage and I am trying to pick up the information in the page.

Most likely incorrectly, I took inspiration from a [similar question on beautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570780/using-python-and-beautifulsoup-saved-webpage-source-codes-into-a-local-file). The beautifulSoup solution works for me (BeautifulSoup 4.6.0).

In contrast, the following, based on roboBrowser, does not seem to work:

```
 from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
 br = RoboBrowser(parser='html.parser') 
 br.open(open("my_file.html"))
```

with error:

> **MissingSchema:** Invalid URL "<_io.TextIOWrapper
>   name='my_file.html'
>   mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>": No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant
>   http://<_io.TextIOWrapper
>   name='my_file.html'
>   mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>?

I understand that the code expected a "http"-based url. I tried prepending "file://" to the absolute path of my file, to no avail.

Is there any way to communicate with the library that it is a local file, or perhaps such functionality is not part of roboBrowser?

Comment: Why do you have 2 open statements on the 3rd line?  It should just be br.open ("my_file.html").