# How do I fix the beautifulsoup error in python while working on a web scraping project?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the error it is showing:

```
value error
Traceback (most recent call last).
```

Code:

```
url = "www.flipkart.com"
html = urlopen(url)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write good questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python and BeautifulSoup (saved webpage source codes into a local file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570780/using-python-and-beautifulsoup-saved-webpage-source-codes-into-a-local-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided code is far from a **[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** but I think the problem is that the `"www.flipkart.com"` is missing the `http://` protocol prefix.

Try `url = "http://www.flipkart.com"`.