# "illegal multibyte sequence" error from BeautifulSoup when Python 3

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, unicode, beautifulsoup

.html saved to local disk, and I am using BeautifulSoup (bs4) to parse it.

It worked all fine until lately it's changed to Python 3.

I tested the same .html file in another machine Python 2, it works and returned the page contents.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('page.html'), "lxml")
```

Machine with Python 3 doesn't work, and it says:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 298670: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Searched around and I tried below but neither worked: (be it 'r', or 'rb' doesn't make big difference)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('page.html', 'r'), "lxml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('page.html', 'r'), 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('page.html', 'r'), 'html5lib')
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('page.html', 'r'), 'xml')
```

How can I use Python 3 to parse this html page?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like the HTML is probably declaring the wrong encoding. I don't know how you'd override that, though.

Comment: When you say `open('page.html', 'r')`, then Python reads the document as plain-text and tries to decode it with some locale-dependent default, which is apparently GBK in your case. `lxml` should be fine with a binary stream however, so you should try opening it with `open('page.html', 'rb')`. Or you specify the correct encoding with the `encoding=` parameter. Note: depending on how the page was saved, the encoding declaration in the document may or may not be correct.

Comment: @lenz, it says "TypeError: 'from_encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for open()"

Comment: The parameter is called `encoding`, not `from_encoding`.

Comment: @lenz, it says "ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument".

Comment: If you open with `rb` you can't pass an encoding. The encoding is used to decode the binary string into a unicode string, which only happens if you open in text mode.

Comment: It's either or. Either you use binary mode (`'rb'`) and let the HTML parser deal with decoding, or you open a text stream with `open('page.html', 'r', encoding=...)`.

Comment: @lenz indeed, I amended the comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It worked all fine until lately it's changed to Python 3.

Python 3 has by default strings encoded in unicode, so when you open a file as text it will try to decode it.
Python 2, on the other hand, uses bytestrings, instead and just returns the content of the file as-is.
Try opening `page.html` as a byte object (`open('page.html', 'rb')`) and see if that works for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It give 1 more warning, says: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

Comment: That's a warning from BeautifulSoup, see here for how to get rid of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511544/how-to-get-rid-of-beautifulsoup-user-warning

Comment: it's an additional warning message. The problem is still there.

Comment: @MarkK are you saying you opened the document in binary mode (`open(..., 'rb')`), and you still get a `UnicodeDecodeError`?

Comment: @GPhilo, it seems the problem wasn't in the BeautifulSoup part. I posted some changes, which helped solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

2 changes I done and not sure which one (or both) took the effect.

The computer was formatted and reinstalled so some settings are different.

1.In the language settings,

```
Administrative language settings > Change system locale >
```

Tick the box

```
Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support
```

2.on the coding, for example, this is the original line:

```
print (soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'listing-row__price'})[0].text.strip().encode("utf-8"))
```

When the part ".encode("utf-8")" was removed, it worked.

- update on **16th Oct. 2019**
  Above change works, but when the box is ticked. Fonts and texts in foreign language software doesn't display properly.

  ```
  Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support
  ```

When the box was unticked, Fonts and texts in foreign language software are displayed well. But, problem in the question remains.

Solution with the box unticked - both foreign language software and Python codes work:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(pages, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8', errors='ignore'), "lxml")
```

Comment: The second is the one that "solves" your problem, by simply printing the raw byte string instead of trying to encode it as UTF-8. You still have invalid unicode characters in your text, but if that's not important for your usage, ignoring them is a good option ;)

Comment: @GPhilo, however it seems not - when the box "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" unticked, the problem pops again. (when the When the part ".encode("utf-8")" was removed, it doesn't worked.)