# how to read only html from the url using python 3?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the given html given below

```
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <div class="table-responsive grid_class">
    <table class="table lightgallery">
        <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th class="col-md-9">Col A</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Col B</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr>
            <td class="">               
            <span>some text here
            </span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </td>
        <td class="text-nowrap" style="font-size: 13px;"><span>some text here also</span></td>
        </tr>
       
        <tr>
            <td class="">               
            <span>some text here
            </span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </td>
        <td class="text-nowrap" style="font-size: 13px;"><span>some text here also</span></td>
        </tr>   
        
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

How to get only the html not the library in python?

I tried `urllib` library and `request` library but it does not work

Any Help would be appreciated and thanks in Advance

Comment: Since you have tagged `beautifulsoup` why not try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570780/using-python-and-beautifulsoup-saved-webpage-source-codes-into-a-local-file

Comment: What is the end goal? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just to read HTML you could use BeautfulSoup

```py
#python -m pip install beautifulsoup4 lxml

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <div class="table-responsive grid_class">
    <table class="table lightgallery">
        <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th class="col-md-9">Col A</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Col B</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr>
            <td class="">               
            <span>some text here
            </span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </td>
        <td class="text-nowrap" style="font-size: 13px;"><span>some text here also</span></td>
        </tr>
       
        <tr>
            <td class="">               
            <span>some text here
            </span>
        </span>
        </span>
    </td>
        <td class="text-nowrap" style="font-size: 13px;"><span>some text here also</span></td>
        </tr>   
        
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

You can access variables and tags with `.find[_all]` or `.select`
E.g.

```py
ths = soup.find_all('th')
print([col.text for col in ths])
# ['Col A', 'Col B']
```